# Display values from API In Angular 6 page

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-services, angular-components, angular7

I am completely new to frontend dev and trying to display API data in an Angular 6 application and can't figure out how to do it.

I can display values in the top level of the returned details but it's the sub level details I am struggling with.

I am using an Angular 6 app using Routing.

Below is all my code

*Homepage.component.html*

```
<h2>Book ID List</h2>

<button (click)="getBooks()">Get</button>

<div *ngFor="let book of books.items">
  <p>ID: {{book.id}}</p>
</div>
```

I can get the 'ID'

[image]
[image]

I am using a `service` to get the data from the test `API`

**Service.component.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiServiceService {
  url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=HTML5  Wire-frames';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

  getBooks(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
      map(this.extractData));
  }
}
```

**Homepage.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiServiceService } from '../../services/api-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  books: any = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  getBooks() {
    this.books = [];
    this.apiService.getBooks().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.books = data;
    });
  }
}
```

At present this return the following:

[image]

What I want to do is display the value from the 'eBook' which is under the 'saleInfo' level. I know I need to the change the loop for each `array` returned in the HTML but this is where I'm stuck.

Also I'm not sure the code I have is the best, but it's working.  As I said I'm new to all this, and can pull values from top level but not sublevels in the API.

Comment: If you want to display the value of "isEbook". Just use `{{book.saleInfo.isEbook}}`

Comment: what about  `<p>ID: {{book.saleInfo.isEbook}}</p>` ?

Comment: @SaddamPojee your suggestion does not work and if i update my loop from `let book of books.items` to `let book of books` then update my display to `ID: {{book.items.id}}` OR `ID: {{book.items[0].id}}` i get the following error `Error: "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"`

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov Please see above reply

Comment: *ngFor doesn’t work with objects, it works with only arrays and iterables.

Comment: @SaddamPojee ok as i said i am struggling getting my head around all this as im new to FE dev, can you please help and tell me exactly what i am doing wrong. i want to display the ID from the Item and eBook from Items > saleInfo in the `HTML`

Comment: @murday1983, Since your response is an object with "items, kind, totalItems" variables. And *ngFor works for arrays and iterables. So, it will not work if you write `let book of books`. Since, `books` is not an array, but `items` is array. So, thats why for `items` *ngFor can be used. So, you have to write `let book of books.items` if you want to use *ngFor.

Comment: If you want to use `books` as array then change the line `this.books = data;` to `this.books.push(data);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend better naming for your service, `Service.compoent.ts` isn't ideal, `api.service.ts` is much more understandable.

Also you can see that when you subscribe, you are using `data: {}`, this means that the function should expect a value of type `Object`, but I would use `any`, since you use `Observable<any>`

**Now for the problem.**

I have created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4djw2) which does just what you wanted. I think you have got confused with the comments. You don't want to change `let book of books.items` to `let book of books` because you would be iterating over object, which you cannot do in `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line `this.books = data;` to `this.books.push(data);`

Since, if it is `this.books = data;` and because the `books` is of type `any`. It will accept anything. So, now after this line, `this.books = data;` it becomes object which contains value of `data` variable. So, you should use,

```
this.books.push(data);
```

To make it behave like an array too. Then, you can access `books` with `*ngFor`.

So, now in the HTML you can access via *ngFor as:

```
<div *ngFor="let book of books">
  <div *ngFor="let items of book.items">
    <p>ID: {{items.id}}</p>
    <p>ebook: {{items.saleInfo.isEbook}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```